# Validation of specific URL

Tags: java, validation, url

I have a specific link, something like `https://wiki.dummy.com/absolute/path/of/webpage` and I want to check if this URL is valid. Obviously pinging the complete URL is not an option, and though pinging `wiki.dummy.com` works, that doesn't prove that the URL is valid. Is there any other way I could quickly validate and then implement it as Java code?

**UPDATE:**
I found this answer working for me-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18135030/1649068

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating URL in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600291/validating-url-in-java)

Comment: @SanKrish I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right question you mentioned. Please help me out here. The URL I'm specifying does not end with `.com`, that's why I mentioned the complete URL. Does that mean it still works in my scenario too? I'm asking this because the link you provided has examples that end with `.com`

Answer (score 0):

You mean syntactically? 
There are several ways to check using regular expressions. Just google it. One way could be:

```
if (url.matches("^http(s{0,1})://[a-zA-Z0-9_/\\-\\.]+([:][0-9]+)?[a-zA-Z0-9_/\\&\\?\\=\\-\\.\\~\\%]*")) 
    System.out.println("URL is valid");
else 
    System.out.println("NOT valid");
```

Or you mean that URL exists?  
You could use `new URL(url).openConnection()` or use [Apache HttpClient 3.x](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) or [Apache HttpClient 4.x](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/index.html), now part of Apache Components

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(); 
HttpMethod method = new PostMethod(url);
```